# How to target a specific slider using javascript when there is more than one

Tags: javascript

I have 3 sliders on my page I'm a building but i am just curious to know the best way to go about targeting only the active one so the javascript below would work for all of them. Everything seems to work fine if i disable the other 2 sliders. First time I have done something like this.
I'm guessing my javascript selectors may need to change some what to get it to work.

Appreciate any advice on the best way forward.

```js
var sliderSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__slide');
var nextSlide = document.querySelector('.slider__button--next');
var previousSlide = document.querySelector('.slider__button--previous');
var currentSlide = 0;
var currentSlideImg = 0;

//Reset slides
function resetSlides() {
  for (var s = 0; s < sliderSlide.length; s++) {
    sliderSlide[s].classList.remove('active');
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < sliderSlideImg.length; i++) {
    sliderSlideImg[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
}

//Start slides
function startSlide() {
  resetSlides();
  sliderSlide[0].classList.add('active');
  sliderSlideImg[0].classList.add('active');
}

//Previous slide
function slidePrevious() {
  resetSlides();
  sliderSlide[currentSlide - 1].classList.add('active');
  currentSlide--;
  sliderSlideImg[currentSlideImg - 1].classList.add('active');
  currentSlideImg--;
}

previousSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (currentSlide === 0 && currentSlideImg === 0) {
    currentSlide = sliderSlide.length;
    currentSlideImg = sliderSlideImg.length;
  }
  slidePrevious();
});

//Next slide
function slideNext() {
  resetSlides();
  sliderSlide[currentSlide + 1].classList.add('active');
  currentSlide++;
  sliderSlideImg[currentSlideImg + 1].classList.add('active');
  currentSlideImg++;
}

nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (currentSlide === sliderSlide.length - 1 && currentSlideImg === sliderSlideImg.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = -1;
    currentSlideImg = -1;
  }
  slideNext();
});
```

```html
<div class="slider slider--1 active">
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__buttons">
    <span class="slider__button--previous">Previous</span>
    <span class="slider__button--next">Next</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider--2">
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__buttons">
    <span class="slider__button--previous">Previous</span>
    <span class="slider__button--next">Next</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider slider--3">
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__slide">
    <p class="slider__text">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__buttons">
    <span class="slider__button--previous">Previous</span>
    <span class="slider__button--next">Next</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create loop over `.slider` and then use `querySelector` on each item, that way you will have variables for each slider

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slider')).forEach(function(slider) {
    var sliderSlide = slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__slide');
    var nextSlide = slider.querySelector('.slider__buttons--next');
    var previousSlide = slider.querySelector('.slider__buttons--previous');
    ...
});
```

or if you prefer for loop:

```
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; ++i) {
   var slider = sliders[i];
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @jcubic many thanks for this, will be sure to try this out. I have not used Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slider')).forEach(function(slider) {} before I have only ever used the for loop way in my post.

Comment: @Liam you can also use for loop, I've update with example.

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help. Is there any real difference to using either of the above?

Comment: @Liam the only differentce with `for` with `var` is that if you call function that reference the variables inside for or i you will have reference to last slider when you call those functions to fix this you can use `let` instead of `var` or if you can't then you'll need to wrap everything in IIFE `for (...) { (function(slider) {    .....   })(sliders[i]); }` which don't look as nice as forEach.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('.slider--3 .slider__slide')`

but I would recommend to put id's on your sliders and then select

`document.querySelector('#slider--3')`